# Data Binding for eCommerce-like site

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, data-binding

I am curious the method developers use to take items in a database which each have different properties, inserting them into HTML as a DOM element and then allow the user to select these items while still have that data binded so following queries to the database are relative to the users click.

For example, say I have an eCommerce site that sells clothing and apparel. A database may hold productID, productName, productColors, ect.. Now I use this data to create some DOM elements to show all these items on a page.  When a user clicks an item, I want to have a pop-up  that displays all the information including images and everything in an organized way.

Well how can I communicate which item(s) are being selected from the client to the server? There must be many ways that developers handle this but I am not sure how this would be implemented?

Comment: Check out a front end MVC framework. It's a sledgehammer for the *specific* problem your asking, but they abstract lots of the data binding away from you so you can spend your energy elsewhere. There's quite a few, though: http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/

Comment: perfect. thank you.. do you have any you like yourself?

Comment: @JonathanF make this your answer and ill vote it up

Comment: hope that helps!!  Each framework has it's own API learning curve, and if you haven't dealt with any MVC on the server before, there will a conceptual learning curve for all of them, too.  It'll be totally worth all the initial confusion and extra work, though!

Comment: End up settling on one?

Answer (score 0):

Check out a front end MVC framework. It's a sledgehammer for the specific problem your asking, but they abstract lots of the data binding away from you so you can spend your energy elsewhere. There are quite a few, though: addyosmani.github.com/todomvc

For more of a use-case review, check out:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/

Good Luck!